# Cancel page transition animation programmatically in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How can I cancel the page transition animation programmatically in nativeScript?

Comment: With 'cancel' you mean how to do a navigation without showing a transition?

Comment: Yes, currently I only found a way through this: <Button text="no transition" [nsRouterLink]="['/main']" pageTransition="none"></Button>. but in some cases you may require do it programmatically e.g using: routerExtensions.navigate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `animated: false` in NavigationOptions to disable the transition programmatically:

```
this.routerExtensions.navigate(["PATH"], {
    animated: false
});
```

This is possible by injecting the routerExtensions instance via the constructor of your component:

```
constructor(private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions)
```

For more information see the {N} [docu](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation#specifying-page-transitions) about specifiying a page transition.